# Turn input field value into array of strings

Tags: jquery, html, input

I am working with an API that accepts an array of strings from an input field called #tags. What is the best way to do that? It should also remove any commas between the "tags" and be [] if no tags.

input: tag1, tag2, tag3
becomes: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]

HTML

```
<input id="tags" type="text" placeholder="tags" name="" value="">
```

how im currently getting the tag value:

```
createPost('canvasID',{tags:$('#tags').val()});
```

Comment: `myString.split(',')` will become `["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `split` function:

```
var valueInserted = $("#tags").val(); // "tag1,tag2,tag3, "two words""
var tags = valueInserted.split(",");  // ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "two words"]
```

Also, `trim()` your strings from tags array:

```
for (var i in tags) {
    tags[i] = tags[i].trim();
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hbw5w/)

Or inline, using regex:

```
 var tags = $('#tags').val().split( /,\s*/ );
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hbw5w/1/)

Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsplit).

Comment: $.trim() if you wish to support older IE version, anyway +1

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thanks. I prefer to split and then to trim.

Comment: @roasted I don't care about IE while I am a Linux fan, but thanks for vote! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string by using a regex that looks for a comma followed by possible whitespace:

```
var yourArray = $('#tags').val().split( /,\s*/ );
```

and then

```
createPost('canvasID',{tags: tagsArray});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fsplit) function.

```
createPost('canvasID',{tags:$('#tags').val().split(',')});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var res = name.replace(/["]+/g, ""); // remove """"               

 

   global with /g
   var resa = res.replace(/[[]+/g, ""); // remove [
   var reso = resa.replace(/[,]+/g, "");// chop            //,,,,,
   str = reso.substring(0, reso.length - 1);//         finally   chop off last ]
// you can chop off all double quotes after
```